# Drop specific rows from multiindex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe that looks like this:

```
 start      grad
 1995-96    1995-96 15  15  
            1996-97 6   6   
            2002-03 1   1   
            2007-08 1   1
```

I'd like to drop by the specific values for the first level (level=0). In this case, I'd like to drop everything that has 1995-96 in the first index.

Comment: there are better ways, but: `df.select(lambda row: row[0] != '1995-96', axis=0)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) takes level as an optional argument

`df.drop('1995-96', level='start')`

As of v0.18.1, its docstring says:

> ```
> """
> Signature: df.drop(labels, axis=0, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise') 
> Docstring: Return new object with labels in requested axis removed.
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     labels : single label or list-like
>     axis : int or axis name
>     level : int or level name, default None
>         For MultiIndex
>     inplace : bool, default False
>         If True, do operation inplace and return None.
>     errors : {'ignore', 'raise'}, default 'raise'
>         If 'ignore', suppress error and existing labels are dropped.
>
>     .. versionadded:: 0.16.1
> """
> ```

Comment: If the first index had not been named as 'start', you could use `level=0`

Comment: Always best to use named index levels due to possible reordering.